# Creating a unique ID that is a concatenation of several data types

Tags: sql, formatting

I'm trying to make a unique ID in a view that is a concatenation of several data types.  First I have DateID, which is a smallint, then I have LinkID which is an int, and lastly I have PicDateStamp which is a datetime.

I'm trying to create one unique ID, so I'm doing this:

```
Convert(varchar, T.DateID + '-' + P.LinkID + '-' P.PicDateStamp) as UTableID
```

For some reason it's returning a long date.  I just want it to look something like (assume DateID is 22, LinkID is 74 and the date of PicDateStamp is 1/15/2018): 22-74-20180115.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are using SQL Server (the `+` for string concatenation suggests this).

Convert to strings *before* concatenation:

```
(convert(varchar(255), T.DateID, 121) + '-' +
 convert(varchar(255), P.LinkID) + '-' +
 convert(varchar(255), P.PicDateStamp, 121)
) as UTableID
```

Note that this uses `convert()` rather than `cast()` so you can specify the format you want for the dates.

Comment: Beautiful!  I changed that datestamp to 110 since I didn't need the hours, etc..., but the rest worked like a charm.